# Generic Methods Where One Inherits From the Other

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I've got the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Context<T>
{
    public List<(string, Func<string, T>)> listOfStuff {get; set;}
}
```

and the following extension method

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    public static Context<T> Include<T,U>(this Context<T> context, Context<U> addContext) where T : U
    {
        //...
        context.listOfStuff.AddRange(addContext.listOfStuff);
        return context;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to add lists from other contexts where `T` inherits from `U`.

I wanted a constraint on `T` such that it has to inherit from `U` which is why I put in `where T : U`

The issue I have is that it states that I can't convert from `List<(string, Func<string, U>)>` to `List<(string, Func<string, T>)>`.

Although `T` inherits from `U` and should therefore have all the fields that `U` have and more.

How can I change the extension method so that it will work and have the constraint?

**UPDATE**

I had made a mistake and have updated the `Context<T>` the `Func` was meant to have been the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to transform elements via `Select`. The following compiles:

```cs
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    public static Context<T> Include<T, U>(this Context<T> context, Context<U> addContext) where T : U
    {
        //...
        var newItems = addContext.listOfStuff
            .Select<(string, Func<U, string>), (string, Func<T, string>)>(t => (t.Item1, x => t.Item2(x)));

        context.listOfStuff.AddRange(newItems);
        return context;
    }
}
```